# npm stuck at "Starting the development server..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2

I know this topic has been created before, but nothing I tried could fix it. The problem is precisely the following. I have a react script on an AWS ec2 server, that I want to execute automatically, whenever the instance is starting. For this purpose, the following script is executed at the start of the AWS server:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time
import shlex, subprocess

args = shlex.split('sudo su ubuntu -c "/usr/bin/npm start --prefix /home/ubuntu/my-app > /home/ubuntu/output.txt 2>&1"')
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

When I run the script manually, everything works just fine. But whenever it is run during the server start, I get the following log:

```
> my-app@0.1.0 start /home/ubuntu/my-app
> react-scripts start

^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: Project is running at http://172.31.14.57/
^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: webpack output is served from
^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: Content not from webpack is served from /home/ubuntu/my-app/public
^[[34mℹ^[[39m ^[[90m｢wds｣^[[39m: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...
```

That's all - nothing happens. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? I thought it had something to do with the fact, that it is started from root. So I tried to fix that by using `sudo su ubuntu -c`, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to use the development server in production?

Comment: How did you configure it to run at start?

Comment: The project is just for demonstration purposes, I want that the employees can easily test the functionality of the application by simply starting the AWS server and then connecting over port 3000. How can I check the configuration at start? I didn’t configure anything specifically so everything should be at default settings.

Comment: Hi @spadel, first off, I would like to clarify a few things before attempting at a solution. I can see that you are using a shell script that runs when the instance launches. Are you using run-instances? (run instances allows aws cli to perform base64 encoding).

Comment: Another way of looking at this is that since AWS EC2 runs in a linux environment. I would like to ask if you created a systemd file for this specific shell script?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's the same problem as [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8688). When you call `npm start` by default it calls the `start` script in `package.json` which points to :

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

There was a change in react-scripts that checks for non interactive shell when `CI` variable is not set [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/commit/7e6d6cd05f3054723c8b015c813e13761659759e)

But when you start it using `sudo su ubuntu -c`, it starts a non interactive shell.

What could work is setting `CI` variable to `true` like this :

```
export CI=true
sudo su ubuntu -c "/usr/bin/npm start ....."
```

You can also create a new script inside `package.json` :

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "ec2-dev": "CI=true;export CI; react-scripts start",
  .....
}
```

and run :

```
/usr/bin/npm run ec2-dev
```

instead of `npm start`

---

Starting a development server is only useful if you mount the `src` folder to a local directory via nfs or other file sharing mechanism in order to use the `nodemon` capability of react-script to instantly restart your server for live changes during development.

If it's for other purposes. You need to build the app using :

```
npm run build
```

Provision the `build` directory artifacts and serve it using a web server